# Angular with IBM carbon design

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to user carbon component in my angular application.

I included the given scss `"../node_modules/carbon-components/scss/globals/scss/styles.scss"` in my angular-cli file.

Now I am trying to use Modal in my component class as suggest [here](http://carbondesignsystem.com/getting-started/developers). but it's not working.I am unable to use Modal custom event in angular component file.

I am stucked from 2 days now I am reading library. If anyone have experience of Carbon Component.Please suggest...

Comment: please post your relevant code or provide a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can provide CDN links in your index.html

- CSS   https://unpkg.com/carbon-components/css/carbon-components.min.css
- ES5   https://unpkg.com/carbon-components/scripts/carbon-components.min.js

as shown [here](http://carbondesignsystem.com/getting-started/developers).

example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SignupFormProject</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" https://unpkg.com/carbon-components/css/carbon-components.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/carbon-components/scripts/carbon-components.min.js"></script>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Girish .. I tried to include CDNs as mentioned but alignment is not as expected. My page is looking very ugly.